# Resolving template from resources/templates _and_ string

Tags: spring, spring-boot, templates, thymeleaf

In my application I need to use "hardwired" html templates which I will bake in by adding them to `resources/templates` and "dynamic" text templates that I want to store in `String`s at runtime.

My code looks similar to this:

```
@Autowired
SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine;

templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(new DynamicTemplateResolver());

Context context = new Context();
context.setVariable("foo1", ... );

templateEngine.process("eitherStaticOrDynamic", context, output);
```

The problem lies within `DynamicTemplateResolver` which implements `ITemplateResolver`. I tried to use the examples given at [Process string templates with thymeleaf 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39062780/process-string-templates-with-thymeleaf-3), but they seem to no longer work on current versions of Spring.

How can I resolve a template from `String`s ? I use Spring Boot 2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I found the solution. My mistake was based on a misunderstanding. Thymeleaf provides a [`StringTemplateResolver`](https://www.thymeleaf.org/apidocs/thymeleaf/3.0.7.RELEASE/org/thymeleaf/templateresolver/StringTemplateResolver.html) with this javadoc:

> ... This template resolvers will consider the template being resolved
>   as the template itself, this is, its contents. No external file or
>   resource will be therefore accessed. ...

Hidden (at least to me) in this comment is the fact that instead of searching for a templates *name* the given string is considered a *template*. That means if you provide `foo = [(${foo})]` this is not considered as a template that needs to be looked up by name but instead treated as a (in this case: text) template !

This and changing my code to this solved the issue for me:

```
StringTemplateResolver tr = new StringTemplateResolver();
tr.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.TEXT);
```

Without this setting my template was not resolved because text mode templates follow a different syntax than html templates.